# Can anyone explain this "repository - entity"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture

I was reading this article:

http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-3-2/

And i seen this code:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    IEnumerable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string children);
}
```

I'm not c# programmer, (i'm python programmer) can anyone explain this interface?

this repository should add an entity to the repository, or update an existing entity, or delete an existent entity, but i cant understand this definition:

```
void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
```

and these others:

```
IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
```

this is for retrieve some desired entities? (how is passed the filter? is a map like

```
{"id": ">5", "color": ["red", "blue"]},
```

or is a simple DQL query STRING?

```
IEnumerable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string children);
```

i don't understand this another function, what is the children param? :/

Comment: what does this question have to do with python ?

Comment: a class translation to python can help me, i don't understand this type hintings (Expression<Fun<T, bool>> filter, etc, or explanation should be good too

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Func<T, bool >>
```

is usually satisfied with a predicate, commonly stated as lambda expression

```
x => x.Property > 5 && x.OtherProperty.Contains( "foo" )
```

The compiler creates expressions out of lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking can be summarised as [what is linq](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). Once you grasp this topic you should begin to understand the code you've shown.

```
Func<>
```

([here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/func)) is a really cool part of .NET. It enables us to write [lambda](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda)'s which are even cooler! ([php has lambda's too](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures))

And

```
Expression<>
```

([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738645%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is a way to define all the above so that it can be "interpreted later". The most obvious example is Entity Framework which will convert lambda expressions into SQL when required.